# <SELECT multiple> - how to allow only one item selected?

Tags: html, html-select

I have a `<SELECT multiple>` field with multiple options and I want to allow it to have only one option selected at the same time but user can hold CTRL key and select more items at once.

Is there any way how to do it? (I don't want to remove 'multiple').

Comment: @GordonM yeah totally :P I was looking for the same today because I wanted multiple items to _show_ (which is implied with the `multiple` attribute) without actually being able to select multiple. Forgot that the attribute to do this was called `size`, so the top answer served me well :)

Comment: I personally have a select multiple field where I have four options and I want three of the options to be able to be selected but the fourth one needs to be alone if selected because it would clash with the other three (3 options and a "none")

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Just don't make it a select multiple, but set a size to it, such as:

```
  <select name="user" id="userID" size="3">
    <option>John</option>
    <option>Paul</option>
    <option>Ringo</option>
    <option>George</option>
  </select>
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q2vo8nge/

Comment: Is it possible to programmatically count total number of <option> in size attribute?

Comment: @Natasha You can get the value of the size field using jquery :-)

Comment: **Size relevant info:** Placing the `select` inside a `display: flex` container, and do `flex-grow: 1` on the `select` will cause it to treat `size="3"` as a minimum height, and then snap the height of the whole select to the maximum size possible within your container. https://jsfiddle.net/z1gypahs/

Answer (score 29):

If the user should select only one option at once, just remove the "multiple" - make a normal select:

```
  <select name="mySelect" size="3">
     <option>Foo</option>
     <option>Bar</option>
     <option>Foo Bar</option>
     <option>Bar Foo</option>
  </select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nymos/G3e63/)

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you want to remove the `multiple` attribute?  The entire purpose of that attribute is to specify to the browser that multiple values may be selected from the given `select` element.  If only a single value should be selected, remove the attribute and the browser will know to allow only a single selection.

Use the tools you have, that's what they're for.

Comment: ah. the size attribute works also standalone. didn't noticed. thanks

Comment: @simPod the reasoning being because there are times where clients need to see all the options in front of them, but can only choose 1 of them.  It's been so long since I've written "real" html, that I had to google/bing the answer... Oh thank heaven for StackOverflow some days.

Answer (score 1):

You want only one option by default, but the user can select multiple options by pressing the CTRL key. This is (already) exactly how the SELECT multiple is meant to behave.

See this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Awww I understand the question now, thanks to Marcos Placona. Initial question wasn't well worded.

Comment: Although I personally think it is "unfair" to the user's experience when you show multiple select options but the user can only select one.

Answer (score 1):

I had some dealings with the select \ multi-select
this is what did the trick for me

```
<select name="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Foo Bar</option>
    <option>Bar Foo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="flowers" size="5" style="height:200px">
 <option value="1">Rose</option>
 <option value="2">Tulip</option>
</select>
```

This simple solution allows to obtain visually a list of options, but to be able to select only one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add verbose description

Answer (score 0):

I am coming here after searching google and change thing at my-end.

So I just change this sample and it will work with jquery at run-time.

```
$('select[name*="homepage_select"]').removeAttr('multiple')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajayendra2707/ejkxgy1p/5/

Comment: You're basically doing what the accepted answer is doing, but in a convoluted way. Instead of removing the multiple attribute at run-time, you can just directly remove it in the HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/3rkk6m9a/

Answer (score -1):

Late to answer but might help someone else, here is how to do it without removing the 'multiple' attribute.

```
$('.myDropdown').chosen({
    //Here you can change the value of the maximum allowed options
    max_selected_options: 1
});
```

Comment: Note: This requires the jQuery Chosen plugin: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/