# Select List iPhone allowing multiple selections, can i force single selection?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile, knockout.js

Im having an issue were on the iPhone my select dropdowns bound in knockout are allowing the iPhone user to select multiple items, the select scrollwheel comes up, is there any way i can force it to only allow single values. Below is my code.

```
<select name="homePersonalLiabilityCoverage" data-bind="options: $root.homePersonalLiabilityCoverages, optionsText: 'homePersonalLiabilityCoverageText', value: homePersonalLiabilityCoverageId, optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Here's a screenshot of what im explaining:[image]

https://insureflo.com/#/autoquoteform/93210

Also, above is a link to the page on the web that is causing the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just not setting it to multiple that should not allow multiple selections but if you want you can force the size attribute

-

[<SELECT multiple> - how to allow only one item selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338229/select-multiple-how-to-allow-only-one-item-selected)

Comment: i thought so too, i don't understand why its doing that only on the iPhone.

Comment: Did forcing the size attribute help?

Comment: Going to test it soon, will report back.

Comment: How would I remove the checkmarks next to each item in the list, for example like the screenshot here, im not sure why those checkmarks are still showing up: http://www.techotopia.com/images/e/ed/Ios_4_iphone_picker_example_layout.jpg

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the issue i was describing is a known issue with ios select boxes and knockout binding. The fix can be found here:

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/472