# html select options from text area type box

Tags: html

[image]

on the left hand side of the image, there is a text area like box in which there are multiple options! on click of any single option, a table is generated on the right hand side!

i have no clue if the box on the left hand side is a text area or not, so i want to know
1) if its a text area or html provides tags for doing it
2) how to make those options where on click, you get table on the right
3) how to keep the clicked option selected

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Maybe you could try reproducing the issue here (https://jsfiddle.net/) and adding it to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it's not a `textarea`, it's a `select` tag: `<select multiple> ... </select>`
2. Add a click handler to each `<option>`. For example, with jQuery: `$('option').click(function(evt){...});` or a change event handler to the select field: `$('select').change(function(evt){...});`
3. They stay selected automatically (and as the attribute of the select tag specifies, you can select multiple values by holding down `CTRL` or `SHIFT` keys).

Comment: yes thanks a lot! its <select multiple>  ... </select> for those who reach this page for reference il also state that <select size="3">..</select> will show just 3 options if you have >3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338229/select-multiple-how-to-allow-only-one-item-selected     refer to this link for more on it.